# Find Inactive Ad users but Guest

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have been using the below code to find inactive Ad users who haven't logged in in the last 30 days, which is working pretty well.

Now I want to exclude a few users from the results which I need help on. I want to exclude `Guest` and `krbtgt`, potentially also excluding any accounts with the terms `temporary` or `template`.

```
import-module activedirectory 
$domain = "%domain%" 
$DaysInactive = 30 
$time = (Get-Date).Adddays(-($DaysInactive))

# Get all AD User with lastLogonTimestamp less than our time and set to enable
Get-ADUser -Filter {LastLogonTimeStamp -lt $time -and enabled -eq $true} -Properties LastLogonTimeStamp |

# Output Name and lastLogonTimestamp into CSV
select-object Name,@{Name="Stamp"; Expression={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.lastLogonTimestamp)}} | export-csv %ltsvcdir%\Nem\InactiveUsers.csv -notypeinformation
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please try to show us what you tried to solve the problem, so what you tried to filter the output. Please take a look at [ask] and [tour]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter out users that contains a word or character with Get-ADUser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51760478/filter-out-users-that-contains-a-word-or-character-with-get-aduser)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just expand your filter to include the rest of the requirements on Get-ADUser

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {(LastLogonTimeStamp -lt $time) -and (enabled -eq $true) -and (Name -notlike "*Guest*") -and (Name -NotLike "*krbtgt*") -and (Name -NotLike "*temporary*") -and (Name -NotLike "*template*")} -Properties LastLogonTimeStamp
```

Comment: Is there any way we can pass the filter Name through a variable? I want to pass multiple values comma separated through a variable.